Utilizing Calculation Groups to apply YoY Time Intelligence to percentage (%) measures
Background
My data uses a 4-4-5 Fiscal Calendar that starts partway through the Gregorian calendar. This means I cannot take advantage of the built in Time Intelligence calculations in DAX. Additionally, I have a large number of measures, and a large number of time periods that need to be available as a reporting option. (ex: rolling 13wk, rolling 52wk, MTD, QTD, YOY, YOY %, etc.)
Rather than creating individual calculations for each, I have created custom Time Intelligence calculation items with in a calculation group that apply time based logic to the selected measure.
I have built logic to create rolling time frames, period to date, Year over Year (YoY), etc.  that work with my calendar.  Everything works except...
The Problem
When I apply my YoY (Current Year (CY) of the Selected Measure - Prior Year (PY) of the Selected Measure) calculation item to a % measure (ex: Gross Margin % (GM%)) it, takes the CY GM% - PY GM% which is not correct.  The right way to calculate this would be to take the YOY values of the component parts and then re-divide.
The Question
Is there a way to build logic into a calculation item that will break a measure down into it's component parts and re-calculate it?  I don't think there is, but I figured I would see if there is a clever solution I am missing before I start making measures with built in Time intelligence (like YoY GM%) that will complicate the downstream usage of the model.

Some data please?
